# Jpegoptim caused images to disappear

Tags: linux, centos, jpeg, centos6

I finally figured out how to get jpegoptim properly installed on my Centos 6 system and ran the command on a larger folder of images like this

```
jpegoptim *.jpg --strip-all
```

Now none of the images appear on my website! They are still in the folder and considerably compressed, but they don't appear to be accessible. I am assuming this must be a permissions issue? Has anybody experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out. For some reason, jpegoptim changes the permissions on the file when you run it. After changing the permissions to 755 (-rwxr-xr-x) using the command chmod -R 755 [containing_folder] the images are now visible again.